# How to download all mp3 files linked in a website with wget?

Tags: linux, wget

The links in the page 'http://www.examplepage.com/' are to a different page 'http://www.archive.org/download/examplepage/asdf.mp3'. How would I write the wget command?

```
wget -mH -A mp3 http://www.examplepage.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stackoverflow question should answer your question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030148/wget-doesnt-download-recursively-after-following-a-redirect

In short, you should use `--recursive` along with `--level=10`, `-H` (which you already have) and `--domains=www.archive.org` to limit the recursion to the domains you want.